# How can I convert this Objective-c to swift? [[XHAudioPlayerHelper shareInstance] setDelegate:(id<NSFileManagerDelegate>)self];

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
[[XHAudioPlayerHelper shareInstance] setDelegate:(id<NSFileManagerDelegate>)self];
```

I want to translate this OC to swift.

I tried that :

```
XHAudioPlayerHelper.shareInstance().delegate = self as! NSFileManagerDelegate
```

But couldn't compiled with error of : ambiguous use of delegate,

Comment: My view controller has many delegate already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `shareInstance` perchance return an object of type `id`? In that case the compiler would have no idea what type it is getting and hence which type of delegate is expected.

If so then amend it to return `instancetype` if possible; as a fallback perform something like:

```
let sharedInstance = XHAudioPlayerHelper.shareInstance() as! XHAudioPlayerHelper
sharedInstance.delegate = ...
```

Comment: ChatDetailsViewController.swift:374:68: Cast from '() -> AnyObject!' to unrelated type 'XHAudioPlayerHelper' always fails

Comment: The shared instance in OC is like this:
`+ (id)shareInstance {
    static XHAudioPlayerHelper *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[XHAudioPlayerHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}`

Comment: I missed some brackets; you understand what I'm saying though? `id` doesn't tell the compiler what type back to expect. So it can't figure out what kind of object it will get from `.delegate`.

Comment: Thanks :) It works now: `let sharedInstance = XHAudioPlayerHelper.shareInstance() as! XHAudioPlayerHelper
            sharedInstance.delegate = self`